Ceph: limit client rights to specific subvolume only
Background story: I want to limit ceph client rights to the specific subvolumegroup/subvolumes only.
Our ceph cluster is general SDN storage for large university and provides access not only to several kubernetes clusters, but also for different services which mount different RBD and CephFS shares from different pools.
For our Openshift kubernetes cluster I want to provision 1 subvolumegroup where they can freely create subvolumes (PVCs) and delete them, create snapshots, do whatever they want.
However, I want to restrict them, not to be able to create/delete subvolumes in any other group.
They mount volumes via cephfs.
They already utilize RBD for pods PVCs provisioning with use of cephfs-csi rbd, but want to provision PV that are shared between several pods (web server clusters). For that purpose is cephfs-csi used (cephfs mounts).
That's the background story. Now to the implementation. After reading ceph docs: from Redhat and official quincy docs, I came up with this client authorizations:
[client.zzz]
    key = <key_here>
    caps mds = "allow rw path=/volumes/csi_vol_group"
    caps mon = "allow r"
    caps osd = "allow rw pool=volumes"
    caps mgr = "rw"

Client zzz has cephfs access to the pool volumes and to the path /volumes/csi_vol_group.
This path is created when subvolumegroup csi_vol_group is created in that pool:
ceph fs subvolumegroup create cephfs csi_vol_group --pool_layout volumes
caps mgr = "rw" is needed so that user can create volumes. Without it, ceph throws error:
Error EACCES: access denied: does your client key have mgr caps? See http://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/mgr/administrator/#client-authentication
However, after setting these client rights, this user can not only create/delete subvolumes within this group, but in any group to which it is not authorized, for example csi_vol_group2:
ceph -n client.zzz --keyring=ceph.client.zzz.keyring fs subvolume create cephfs forbidden_volume --group_name csi_vol_group2

ceph fs subvolume ls cephfs csi_vol_group2
[
    {
        "name": "forbidden_volume"
    }
]

I am obviously doing something wrong. Does anyone know, preferably from experience, how can these client authorizations be limited to the specific subvolumegroup/subvolume within cephfs?
